# SQL Server XML Path causes empty cells in Excel

Tags: sql, xml, excel, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query running perfectly in SQL Server 2008 :

```
SELECT
    lk.Varenummer, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT lst.Placering + '  ' AS [text()]
     FROM c5.dbo.lpstatustmp lst
     WHERE lst.varenummer = lk.Varenummer
     FOR XML PATH('')) AS Placering
FROM 
    Lagkart lk
```

Which returns 2 columns:

```
Varenummmer          Placering
-----------          ---------
Varenummer1           ABC
Varenummer2           ABC DEF
```

Everything outputting as expected from the SQL Server.

When copy/pasting this query into Excel (using MS query), all "Placering" cells are empty however. I assume that this is because of how Excel perceives the "XML" although it's raw. Is there any other way to pass this concatenated result in a way Excel (2010) understands?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Apparently, it's possible to CAST the full expression :

```
 ...
 CAST((SELECT DISTINCT lst.Placering + '  ' AS [text()]
 FROM c5.dbo.lpstatustmp lst
 WHERE lst.varenummer = lk.Varenummer
 FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Placering
 ...
```

And that way, Excel sees it as raw text.